# using php to add div class property

Tags: php, css

I am using WAMP. I want to take background image URL from my database and want to show this in div class 'box'. I tried it by followed way but couldn't succeed. the last background image is appearing on each box while I want to show different images. Code I am using is

```
<?php 
    $feild_set = get_all_feilds();
    while($feild = mysql_fetch_array($feild_set)) { 
        $url = $feild['background_image_url'];
        echo "<style>
            .box { 
                width: 300px ;
                height: 100px;
                background-image: $url;
                background-visibility: visible;
                border: 1px #00FF33;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                display: inline-table;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            </style>";
        echo "<div class=\"box\">";
        echo "<a href=\"content.php?feild=" . $feild['id'] . "\" ><block_holder>{$feild['menu_name']}</block_holder></a>"; 
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: I always wonder if people really write this kind low quality code with no proper indents, or it's just a paste issue. God, why ?

Comment: Could you please show an example of the HTML output / draw a picture of what you expected output should be ....

Comment: And what is `<block_holder>` ?

Comment: It's spelled `field` just for future reference...

Comment: <block_holder is just a tag to make text-indent: -9999px. and formatting is a paste issue.

Comment: @hsz Often it's a side effect of people using editors that treat tabs as spaces. Many of these editors will also auto-indent with tabs and display them as spaces. My girlfriend has her Notepad++ set up to do it and it annoys the hell out of me. But some people are just lazy and write sloppy, unreadable code - then complain when it's hard to debug.

Comment: @cillosis It was better to you to solve problem instead of seeing spelling mistakes etc. Now, i have solved it out with the help of daverandom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 

  echo "
    <style>
      .box { 
        width: 300px ;
        height: 100px;
        background-visibility: visible;
        border: 1px #00FF33;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: inline-table;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
    </style>";

  $field_set = get_all_feilds();

  while ($field = mysql_fetch_assoc($field_set)) {
    echo '
    <div class="box" style="background-image:'.htmlspecialchars($field['background_image_url']).';">
      <a href="content.php?feild='.htmlspecialchars($field['id']).'">
        <block_holder>'.htmlspecialchars($field['menu_name']).'</block_holder>
      </a>
    </div>';
  }

?>
```

---

**What have I done?**

- Placed the declaration of the `.box` CSS class outside the loop so it is only output once
- Changed `mysql_fetch_array()` to [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) as it is less confusing and more efficient
- Removed the `background-image:` property from the `.box` class
- Added a `background-image:` property to an inline `style=` attribute for each div <strike>and wrapped the URL of the image in `url()`</strike> *(this has been undone as it seems the URLs are stored in the database with this already done*
- Passed data from the database through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before outputting it
- Corrected the spelling of `feild` to `field` where it can be done without breaking the rest of your code
- Some general indentation and quote tidying and readability fixes

---

As it was, your CSS `.box` class was declared more than once. Because of the cascading nature of **C**SS, only the values used in the last declaration would have been used - each declaration of a property overrides the last, which is why you were only seeing the last image. You also would not need to declare those details more than once - the whole idea of a class is that you can declare it once and use it multiple times. If you want element-specific properties, use IDs or inline styles (preferably IDs, but I have used inline styles here for simplicity).

Comment: thanx for help DaveRandom but by this code i m not getting any image. there is everything right but background image is not displaying.

Comment: Please can you show the HTML that this code generates? If you view source on the resulting page, then either edit the question with it or put it somewhere like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: i have uploaded it on pastebin. http://pastebin.com/nXP5HQQP is the link. Check it out

Comment: @user1186989 My apologies, I added `url()` around the image URLs, but it would seem that are already stored in your database like this. See minor edit above.

Comment: Thanx a lot DaveRandom.....You are a star . You solved it out in minutes while i was trying from hours as I am new to css. One last question can we add more than one property using inline styles.

Comment: @user1186989 Yes, no problem adding as many properties as you like, just make sure they are all terminated with a `;` - e.g. `<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">` is valid.

Comment: As a side note, it would be better for you to stored the URLs in the database just as URLs, without being wrapped in `url()` - this means you could use them in other places as well. As it is, you can only use them for CSS.

Comment: thanx again and Bye. Have a gud day